# Adding Files to Page Only Adds Title, Doesn't Create Link

Tags: media, links

I have run into a really weird problem. When I go to add a file to a page or post using the Add Media button, Wordpress only inserts the title of the file and doesn't create the link, it's only the text title of the file. If I click to view the Text editor, it only shows the title.

I have disabled all the plugins and switched to the Twenty Twenty theme, but the problem persists. If anyone can give me any insight, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Which editor are you experiencing this in? What kind of file? What's the file type?

Comment: I have used both Gutenberg and the Classic Editor, the file is any type including PDF, Word, Excel etc.